# Laravel 5.8 Sistema multi base de datos

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

Estoy creando un programa que debe de ser multi base de datos. La idea es que según el usuario conecte con una base de datos dedicada a ese usuario en concreto. He buscado por todos sitios y lo único que encuentro es hacer una consulta concreta a otra base de datos, no cambiar todo el programa para que apunte a otra base de datos. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que son usuarios limitados, puedes usar el atributo `connection` que tiene el modelo

```
class Modelo extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection = 'conexion_1';
}
```

Para alterarlo solo tienes que usar `setConnection`

```
 $modelo = new Modelo;
 $modelo->setConnection('conexion_2');
 $modelo = $modelo->find(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes plantear usar un middleware.
Plantea enviar un parámetro a tu solicitud para identificar a que base debes conectarte según el usuario y evalualo en el middleware.

Por ejemplo supongamos que te conectas a la base "juan-db", en tu peticion añade el parametro llamado "usuario"

```
$usuario = $request->headers->get('usuario');
$db = $usuario. '-db';
```

Luego setea o inicia una conexión:

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $db);
DB::reconnect();
```

Para asegurarte que la conexion se realizo puedes imprimir un mensaje en el logger

```
logger('Conectado a: ' . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.database'));
```

con eso podras conectarte a una base diferente, segun el usuario.

Comment: Esto tiene buena pinta, el problema es que hahora me dice: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Config' not found`

Comment: Agrega el siguiente use en tu archivo.
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;`